# Top margin (auto-layout)

Tags: ios, autolayout

I set Right Margin for white rect (view) - 1.008

[image]

Now I want to set Top Margin - 1.1, but nothing changes (doesn't matter what I set for Multiplier), white rect is still at the top of black rect without any margin:

[image]

p.s. I don't want to use constants (I want to set margins in percentages depends on parent view, seems multiplier is designed for this)

**Update** (example of what I want)

[image]

Comment: you can drag the Top margin a little and then try to set the Constraints. If it gives red line then go to Resolve Auto Layout Issues and click on the Add Missing Constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autolayout here works as expected. Your problem is a simple math problem. Your superview top is located at 0, and for your constraint this holds (read more about constraints anatomy [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html)):

```
yourView.top = multiplier * superView.top + constant
```

After filling in the values:

```
yourView.top = 0 * 1.1 + 0
```

Which is simply:

```
yourView.top = 0
```

In your question the right spacing works, because the `superView.right` definitely larger than 0 (from what I see on the picture, it's closing to `UIScreen.main.bounds.width`).

**Update**

To get what you want, I would normally recommend using `UILayoutGuide`, but since you are using storyboards (where it is not supported), you will have to add a dummy transparent `UIView`.

The layout to get what you want would need to look like this (I used `.red` color instead of `.clear` so that you can see what I am trying to achieve):

[image]

In this scenario, you will need to set up following constraints. I will use programmatic way of setting them, but I believe you can easily read them and transform them to storyboards:

First, constrain the transparent (in my view red) dummy view to the top right corner of the black view - blackView):

```
// by default constant = 0, multiplier = 1
dummyView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blackView.topAnchor).isActive = true
// right or trailing, it's up to you
dummyView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blackView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
```

Then constrain the `dummyView` to be a perfect square (width equal to height):

```
// by default constant = 0, multiplier = 1
dummyView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dummyView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

Keep the right side constraint of the `whiteView` as it was, and use it to determine the size of the `dummyView`:

```
dummyView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: whiteView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
```

After this, `dummyView` will have size of the `offset x offset`, because its left side is constrained to `whiteView.right`, and its right side to `blackView.right`.

So now you finish with one last constraint which will position `whiteView` properly from the top:

```
whiteView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dummyView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: I see now, but it is also interesting how can I get the same value for a top margin as a value for right margin

Comment: @user924 what do you mean same value?

Comment: same offset in pixels (same value) for top and right margin

Comment: @user924 you would have to explain the context about what you are talking

Comment: I will draw an example image and post a link here, pls wait

Comment: I could do something like `yourView.bottom = 0.992 * superView.bottom + 0` but `superView.bottom` != `superView.right` (black rect is not 1:1, width != height)

Comment: @user924 in your question right now, are you aware that you are not setting it to be 1.008 * blackview.width, right? it works like that right now but if you move black view, it will mess it up for you

Comment: I meant `1.008 * blackview.right`, anyway `blackview.right == blackview width`

Comment: blackview matches all height and width of display

Comment: @user924 I think you are overcomplicating the layout, but you can try the approach I suggested in answer update

Comment: I have no problem make something programmatically (this way I have it now), I don't even need autolayout, constraints if using programmatic methods (code) for markup, I just can get display width, height and set everything in percentages. I want to know how can I  use only storyboard, in Android it's much easier, it has weights, `dp`, `sp` which we can use in xml files

Comment: I just left as it was, all my buttons I create/add programmatically... not in storyboard, I'm a bit disappointed. I'm converting (rewriting) Android app to iOS, in Android almost all UI/adaptive markups I did in xml files. I'll accept your answer cause you answered me what was the problem with an example I included in the question

Comment: @user924 I understand your frustration - that's one of the reasons I dont use storyboards at all.. plus autolayout has its limitations after all..